# How to handle query migration in MongoDB / Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, migration, database-migration, morphia

I recently had to introduce **a change in my data structure** regarding the "users" collection which resulted in a migration from the following simplified example:

```
{ 
   "name": "John",
   "emails" : [ "a@a.a", "b@b.b" ]
}
```

to this:

```
{ 
   "name": "John",
   "emailAddresses" : [ 
       { 
         "email" : "a@a.a",
         "verified" : true
       },
       { 
         "email" : "b@b.b",
         "verified" : true
       }
    ]
}
```

So the "**emails**" field was changed from being a simple String array to an array of complex objects, each having a field "email" and "verified". In addition to that, it's name changed to "**emailAddresses**".

I am aware of how to migrate my data concerning loading and storage with changed data models using the annotations provided by Morphia such as `@PostLoad` or `@NotSaved`.

My problem arises with queries. Originally, I would query for users by their email address like this:

```
Query<User> q = dataStore.createQuery(User.class);
q.filter("emails", email);
User u = q.get();
```

I know that I simply have to adapt the query to the following to support my new data structure:

```
Query<User> q = dataStore.createQuery(User.class);
q.filter("emailAddresses.email", email);
User u = q.get();
```

That's fine. The problem is that some of the documents in my collection are still stored in the "old" way, and some are already stored in the "new" way. If I only use the "new" way, I am not going to be able to find older documents.

The question is:

> How can I create a query that considers both old and new data
>   structures when (like in this example) querying by email address?

The best thing I could come up with so far is to use "or" queries and query for both fields with validation disabled (exception thrown otherwise):

```
Query<User> q = dataStore.createQuery(User.class);
q.disableValidation();
q.or(q.criteria("emails").equal(email), q.criteria("emailAddresses.email").equal(email)); 
User u = q.get();
```

> However, this seems quite cumbersome and possibly bad for performance.
>   I was wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why not to update old documents to new format?

Comment: How exactly would that go down? I have a live running server that currently uses the old queries, and a database that uses the old data structure. If I update my server to only use the new queries, queries will fail until e.g. I run my update script. On the other hand, if I update the db first and then the server, queries will also fail for a short period of time. Is there a way to do this without any downtime or disruption?

Comment: Fair enough. 0 downtime wasn't mention in the question.

Comment: No it was not, my bad. Your  suggestion is good, but how would you do it considering the "zero downtime" factor?

Comment: Without downtime I guess there is no alternative to some cumbersome and slow queries. I've done that in the past, then ran some upgrade code (iterating over all entities and changing their structure — not sure if you can do that automatically with the flag), and once everything has been migrated switched to the new structure. Might want to do that while you have less traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use only the Morphia annotations. You can use the MongoDB command line to run update queries. You can do quite complex logic in JavaScript to lookup and transform documents to the new format. You can run it only on documents that still have the old 'emails' field if you have an index on that field and millions of documents

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up writing my own update script which transformed my existing data in a way that both current and new server can handle it. After upgrading to my new server version I ran another "cleanup" script to get rid of the redundant data.